# Output NaN of addition two number in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to multiply two number and add another number but the output is shown NaN. How to solve this?

Here my code

```
medicines = [new Medicine()];

this.sum = 0;// sum also type of number

for (let i = 0; i < this.medicines.length; i++)
{
    this.sum = this.sum + this.medicines[i].price * this.medicines[i].quantity;//here price and quantity of type number
    console.log(typeof this.sum);//but this print NaN
}
```

Model of medicines

```
export class Medicine{
   constructor(){}
   name: String;
   quantity:number;
   price:number
}
```

Comment: whats ```this.medicines``` ?

Comment: this.medicines  is an array of model Medicine.

Comment: They are not two numbers. Addition of two numbers will NEVER produce NaN :) try adding debug output for your price and quantity, you probably have one entry were not both are set. On a side note you can also simplify your code by using a Map.reduce functions instead of for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be something like :

```
medicines:Medicine[]=[{name: 'name', quantity:3, price:6},{name: 'name', quantity:3, price:6},{name: 'name', quantity:3, price:6}]
```

or:

```
medicines: Array<Medicine> = new Array<Medicine>();
```

Comment: @NuruzzamanKhan your welcome you can select the tik element next to my answer to accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

can you do like this

```
this.sum = this.sum + +this.medicines[i].price * +this.medicines[i].quantity;
```

put `+` ahead of property, so it will convert your property value to number if it is not number.

Answer (score 0):

```
medicines: [] = new Medicine();

this.sum = 0;// sum also type of number
for (let i = 0; i < this.medicines.length; i++)
{
    this.sum = this.sum + this.medicines[i].price * this.medicines[i].quantity;//here price and quantity of type number
    console.log(typeof this.sum);//but this print NaN
}
```